# How do I optimize this CSS3/many images for performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css

Here is the [link to site](http://pineapple.io/)

There's a few things going on here I'd love to tweak, I'm not quite sure what else I can do though.

Thumbnails and favicons are pulled via external services, and I'd rather not setup reverse proxy to cache them. Normally, the images are supposed to fade in smoothly when they load (in a sort of 'random' order, it gives it a nice effect).

Youll notice when the page loads, it seems to be a bit choppy though, I think because the twitter script loading at the same  time as all the thumbnails fadein.

I have tried looking at several performance tools but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I can improve this.

The only thing I can think of would be to maybe have twitter offset by a second or two.

Comment: These images and probably some more that aren't on te page now can be combined into a sprite:     /assets/dots.png
    /assets/down.png
    /assets/footer-line.png
    /assets/input-fade.png
    /assets/list.png
    /assets/logo-c903031283d4038601dfb1b8e3da7f45.png
    /assets/scroll-6683c9017943b38961dbdda4f9271747.png
    /assets/standard.png
    /assets/submit-bg.png
    /assets/text-search.png
    /assets/up.png

Comment: I'm not seeing any loading issues...

Comment: Safari looks stunning, chrome has a lot to be desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) and the HTML [`defer`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute. You should also consider packing scripts, moving them to the footer and merging them. The same goes for CSS, and, you should put them in two separate groups, this will cause them to be loaded in two "batches".

Comment: I can't put all those in a sprite, they're external services that are always changing. I could put my several tiny images that I use for voting and such into a sprite but I didn't think it would help that much, considering theres only a few?

Comment: It would help, sprites save server requests not data.

Comment: You also have 111 requests and are loading over 1MB of data, what you might try to do, is merge and cache the external scripts. Oh, forgot to mention, AFAIK putting the JS and CSS in groups is _the_ most important thing to do.

Comment: Rails does this automatically, do you specifically have the name of the script in question? I have to put modernizer as a separate script at the top as it needs to be in the head. My main css file is also in the head. at the bottom is my compressed js file, I'm not sure how else I could optimize it. Thanks!

Comment: True... This question probably belongs on Super User.

Comment: Okay fair enough, I'll ask over there. Thanks

Comment: But, following these techniques, I have a page that's pretty content heavy with only 22 requests, it's 500kb total and it loads and the DOM's calculated in less than 2 seconds. Google's homepage takes 4.  :D

Comment: It was only 10 minor pngs, I didnt think it would really make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Download and install  [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod) for the apache server

Or try [google's page speed up service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service)

[Details on the image optimization component](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-image-optimize)

Comment: From what I understand it just on the fly minifies and compresses assets, which rails does automatically. I see it strips image meta data, is that worth the hassle?

Comment: It also compresses images so that should help a lot with a site that is image intensive.

Comment: put async attribute for all the external javascripts that are not required to be loaded inline.

Comment: Would it compress images that are external as well?

Comment: I don't think so, it can only optimize what your apache server is serving.

Answer (score 0):

You could always preemptively delay the display of images:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('img').css('opacity':'1');
  }, 2000);

});
```

CSS:

```
img{
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity .5s;
}
```